# How to test websites that uses HSTS policies using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, hsts

I have tried recording https websites using Jmeter.

This is list of observations:

1. for not HSTS websites, it creates a self signed certificate when we "Add Exception" and continues to record.
2. For HSTS websites, we cannot "Add Exception".

Is there any way we can record HSTS domains like https://www.google.com ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an alternative way of recording - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Another option is capturing the traffic using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or even [built-in browser developer tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/) to capture the traffic and once done manually creating the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

Comment: Yes, I am able to record using Blazemeter. but I want to know how does Jmeter do it without using Blazemeter extension. Or Jmeter does not support it?

Comment: This is more about the browser you're using rather than JMeter, for example it should be possible with [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1159143)

Comment: I have tried recording with all popular browsers including Chrome, firefox, safari, and IE. Not able to record without the extension.

Comment: Have you followed steps from the above link: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1159143

Comment: Yes, I did. But still get the same problem: This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception to this certificate.